# Windows 8. How to disable Windows key from starting start screen

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-key

I want to disable shortcut for starting windows 8 start screen without disabling all win + x shortcuts or without disabling windows key. I just want to turn off this shortcut.

Is it possible?

Comment: I found something that I want in this example http://www.iobit.com/product-manuals/sm8-help/, there is setting "Press Windows key to open Metro", but maybe it's possible to achieve this without third party app.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Previous method no longer works in RTM version. The only method I can think of is using **Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator**. It's *kind of* 3rd party though it's provided by Microsoft.

[Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/goglobal/bb964665.aspx)

> Create new keyboard layouts from scratch
>
> Base a new layout on an existing one
>
> **Modify an existing keyboard layout and build a new layout from it**
>
> Multilingual input locales within edit control fields
>
> Build keyboard layout DLLs for x86, x64, and IA64 platforms
>
> Package the resulting keyboard layouts for subsequent delivery and
>   installation

I think you might be able to do in the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout though I'm not sure how as it's not as simple as the above method.

Comment: Are you sure this still works in RTM?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I got mixed up. Answer edited.